# python decorator that call a function with delay

Tags: python, timer

why this code does not work?

```
from threading import Timer

def delayed(seconds):
    def decorator(f):
        def wrapper(*args, **kargs):
            Timer(seconds, f, args, kargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator

@delayed(1)
def foo():
    '''this function does not return'''
    print('foo')

foo()
print('dudee')
```

i except this result:
    dudee
    foo

i have only
    dudee

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you didn't start your timer try like this:

```
from threading import Timer

def delayed(seconds):
    def decorator(f):
        def wrapper(*args, **kargs):
            t = Timer(seconds, f, args, kargs)
            t.start()
        return wrapper
    return decorator

@delayed(1)
def foo():

    print('foo')

foo()
print('dudee')
```

Comment: ohu god! i was checking in dir(Timer) without instantiating it! thanks!